# Vote buttons not correctly aligned

Tags: bug, design

[image: incorrectly aligned vote buttons]

As you can see, the question's score is not correctly aligned with the vote buttons, as it is on other Stack Exchange sites. This is caused by a small padding on the left of the vote button images. It happens on this very Meta as well. Can this be corrected?

<sub>Issue reproduced with Chrome and Safari on Mac OS X, and IE on Windows 8.</sub>

Comment: ...Shit, now I can't un-see it.

Comment: I recommend posting this as an answer [here](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4720/new-site-design), because its to do with design and bug

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil from that same question: *If you see any CSS/styling bugs, please start a new post and tag it with design and bug.* You can't tag an answer, so I started a new question instead.

Comment: Ahh okay @Glorfindel, missed that